# Solving a variant of the knapsack problem

Tags: analysis, algorithms

In this my problem, we have a list of n elements ( n not fixed and known) , all positives, containing probably duplicates.

I have a target K ( positif as well)

I would like a way to figure out the sub-set of elements for which the sum is :

Either equal to K

Either the smallest greater than K

So for example :

1,5,5,5,6,50,51
K = 100

The sub-set would be 50,51

I would like to know how to solve this problem ensuring the best way on complexity?

On a second step , it would be better to have the sub-set with smallest numbers ( if many)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you want to find the smallest "subset" with duplicates allowed that has minimum weight $\geq K$? (order by total weight first then smallest subset)

Comment: @gareth : yes :)